# How to prove there are at most three index $2$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2^a$ using classification theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that  $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2^a$ ($a \geq 1$) has at most three subgroups of index $2$. I have my own proof but I wonder if there is a way to use the classification of finitely generated abelian groups.

My Attempt: Let $G = \{ \pm 1 \}$, $H = \mathbb{Z}/2^a$ and $K$ be a subgroup of $G \times H$ of index $2$. Put $S = \{ h \in H : (-1, h) \in K \}$. If $S = \emptyset$, then $K = 1 \times H$. If $S \neq \emptyset$, put $\{\mbox{ord}(h) : h \in S \} = \{ n_1, \cdots, n_l\}$ ($n_1 > \cdots > n_l$). Pick $h_i$ such that $\mbox{ord}(h_i) = n_i$. Then $S_i := \langle(-1, h) \rangle \cap S =\{h^k : k \text{ is an odd integer} \}= \{ h' \in H : \mbox{ord}(h') = \mbox{ord}(h_i)\}$. Thus $$|S| = |S_1| + \cdots + |S_l| = \phi(n_1) + \cdots + \phi(n_l)$$
On the other hand $N = \{ h \in H : (1, h) \in K \}$ is a subgroup of $H$. Now from $|K|=|S|+|N|$ we can conclude (after some calculation) that either (1) $|N| = 2^{a-1}$, $l=1$ and $n_1 = 2^a$ or (2) $|N|=2^{a-1}, l=a$ and $n_i = 2^{a-i}$.